# Hausdorff measure of Lebesgue non-measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

In $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, if $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is not Lebesgue measurable and $\alpha < N$, then $m^{*}_{\alpha}(E)=\infty$.

I have started with the definition of a non-measurable set: there exists a constant $c$ s.t. $\forall \mathcal{O}$ an open set with $E \subset \mathcal{O}$ which satisfies
$$m^{*}(\mathcal{O} \setminus E)>c$$

I know that $m^{*}_{\alpha}(\mathcal{O})=\infty$ and I am trying to show that $m^{*}_{\alpha}(E)\geq m^{*}_{\alpha}(\mathcal{O})$ but I don't know if this approach is correct and I don't know how to continue if so is.

I would appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to show the contrapositive.  Suppose that $E$ is a set with finite $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.  You can actually show that $E$ must have Lebesgue outer measure zero, and in particular it is Lebesgue measurable.

To get started, note that by definition, there must exist $M < \infty$ such that for all sufficiently small $\delta$, there is a covering of $E$ by a sequence of sets $C_i$ such that $d_i := \operatorname{diam}(C_i) \le \delta$ and $\sum_i d_i^\alpha < M$.  Now for each $i$, let $B_i$ be a closed ball of radius $d_i$ centered at some point of $C_i$.  Then $C_i \subset B_i$, so the balls $B_i$ also cover $E$, and we have $m(B_i) = \omega_N d_i^N$ where $\omega_N$ is the volume of the unit $N$-ball.  Now the Lebesgue outer measure $m^*(E)$ can be bounded by
$$m^*(E) \le \sum_i m(B_i) = \omega_N \sum_i d_i^N \le \omega_N \delta^{N-\alpha} \sum_i d_i^\alpha \le \omega_N \delta^{N-\alpha} M.$$
Since $\alpha < N$ by assumption, letting $\delta \to 0$ we have $m^*(E)=0$.

Comment: But then if you prove with this covering you have to be careful about the upper bound, because at this covering it depends of how many balls you have, even if involves $\delta\to 0$, you will multiply with the sum of infinitely many balls...

Comment: @energy: With the argument I have in mind, the number of balls doesn't really enter - everything is in terms of sums over all the sets/balls.  I mean, yes, it will typically not work to consider a covering by balls that are all the same size, but I am not suggesting that.

Comment: Now I get your point, the key is to have the set covered by the balls of a center and radious $diam(C_i)/2$ then you have that: $\sum_i m(C_i)\leq \sum_i m(B(x_i,diam(C_i)/2))\leq \sum_i k_n (\frac{diam(C_i)}{2})^\alpha$ And then as $\delta \to 0$ its going to 0 so its Outer Lebesgue measure is 0, and its measurable.

Comment: @energy: Yes, that's the idea.  However, we really need balls of radius $\operatorname{diam}(C_i)$, not just $\operatorname{diam}(C_i)/2$.  A set of some diameter $d$ cannot necessarily be covered by a ball of diameter $d$ (with radius $d/2$), though it can be covered by a ball of diameter $2d$ and radius $d$. For instance, an equilateral triangle of side length 1 has diameter 1, but will not fit inside a disk of diameter $1$.  So that accounts for the factor of $2^\alpha$ that I mentioned.

Comment: But then you will have that $m^*(E)\leq 2^{\alpha} k_n M$ and this doesnt depend of delta. So you can not $\delta \to 0$.

Comment: @energy: I edited the answer to fill in the details.